# Is it possible to pass TEXT value of <select> to a hidden <input> as its value?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST" action="question-function.php">
  <label>Category</label>
  <select name="catid" id="catid" class="form-control">
    <?php
      $sel3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from category"); //text value from here                                   
      if ($sel3==true) {
        while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel3)) {
          extract($row3);
          echo '<option value='.$cat_id.'>'.$category.'</option>';
        }
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="catname" value=""> //to value of here.
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Post">
</form>
```

Is there a way to get the value and text value of  and pass it to POST separately?
So I can use each of them in extract($_POST);

If its not possible, can I pass the text value of select to a hidden input?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to use javascript

Comment: php is a server side language so will not be triggered when the user updates the selection, you need js to listen to the change and update the hidden input accordingly. But since name and value are coming from db, isn't id enough to post to have also the name? Why do you need this overcomplication?

Comment: Thanks @LelioFaieta, I kinda need both value and text value to be inserted in the DB.

Comment: Yes you could but I don't understand why this would be necessary. The selected value(s) in the `select` will be sent to the server anyway when the form is submitted. You don't need to send the text value, because that shouldn't be necessary in order to process the form. You should only need the selected ID. If you think you need the text value as well then you probably have a design flaw in your application and/or database somewhere. The text should be a fixed value, associated with the ID already in a separate lookup table in your database. You don't need to duplicate it anywhere else.

Comment: in `question-function.php` you post the id of the selected item, query the db for that text and update accordingly the database where you want. You can do it with a single insert query.

Comment: Thanks @MisterJojo, like an onclick event?

Comment: @CleverNever stop trying to solve this problem, and read my comment. You should not need to do this. This is a massive [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - you're trying to do something which HTML forms don't do natively. They don't do it natively because it's **not necessary**. Fix your database design instead.

Comment: @CleverNever  no, with `change` event; see my anwser

Comment: @LelioFaieta like $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_Id='$catid'";

then fetch the text value?

Comment: _"I kinda need both value and text value to be inserted in the DB"_ - if you think you need this, then your database design is flawed, as ADyson already pointed out. If you continue down this path using unnecessary hacks like the one you're asking about, you will only complicate your life further. Any feature you might want to add in the future will be more difficult to implement, because you are adding unnecessary steps in the process. Fix your schema before your application grows and becomes a nuissance to maintain.

Comment: Sorry Sir @ADyson, i just refreshed and read your comment. I'll just try to get the text value on the next .php where the value was passed.

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja , noted. I gotta correct my way of thinking and avoid complicating processes.

Comment: @CleverNever exactly. You can `inner join` any related table to the category table in order to obtain it, using the ID.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a process which is not necessary

Comment: Ok Sir @ADyson, sorry for the trouble everyone.

Comment: double quotes are missing  on `echo '<option value="'.$cat_id.'">'.$category.'</option>';`

Comment: @MisterJojo - Since it's an id, I think we can assume it's a number (without white space and/or other strange characters) and then quotes aren't mandatory.

Comment: Dear what I got from your point is that you want to get category value and category name when form is submitted, there are two ways, one is  to put category value and category name in option tag value separated by commas and on post you can convert it to array and then use them according, or pass the category value and on post query again database to get category name based on category value, let me know if I am not wrong about your requirements than I will post the answer properly in answer snippet.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif I guess you didn't read any of the other comments before posting yours, then? The problem is already solved - the real issue is the OP not understanding how to design their database correctly. Sending the text back with the ID is simply not needed. Instead if they need to show it they can retrieve it from the categories table in the database by joining it by the ID onto any other related table they are selecting from.

Comment: @ADyson I read all comments from start to end, but we are here to help each other that is why I asked few questions.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif Sure that's true, but in this case you're not actually helping, because a) the problem is already solved, and b) you're suggesting something which implements what the OP asked for but isn't actually what the really need. The various comments already explain this, which is why I'm puzzled you're still suggesting that they go down the incorrect route of re-submitting the text. As mentioned earlier this was an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where the person is asking to do something weird because they didn't understand the real way to do what they needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values(s) of the selected item(s) in the `select` will be sent to the server anyway when the form is submitted.  You don't need to send the text value, because that shouldn't be necessary in order to process the form. You should only need the selected ID.

If you think you need the text value as well then you probably have a design flaw in your application and/or database somewhere. The text should be a fixed value, associated with the ID already in a separate lookup table in your database. You don't need to duplicate it anywhere else.

If, at any point later, you need to get the description of the category ID associated with the data which was submitted and inserted into your database, you can `inner join` any related table to the category table in order to obtain it, using the category ID.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with other comments about flawed design but if you really need this, you could do:

```
   echo '<option value="' . $cat_id . '-' . $category . '">' . $category . '</option>';
```

Comment: There's never any need to do it